# Can we have camera controls enabled with AVCaptureSession..?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, avcapturesession

I want to to use AVCaptureSession as I have to fit camera a view in a particular frame (I am not sure if I can fit the camera frame using UIImagePickerController). But I also want to show camera controls (Auto and front/back camera button), does anyone know how I can achieve this..? or will I have to use these as custom buttons.

Comment: Yes you can do this thinks using custom overlay of the camera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use AVCaptureSession, you will have to do all camera controls of your own (adding some overlayview to your AVCaptureSession camera). You can use UIImagePickerController and transform your camera using cameraViewTransform, for example full screen camera transform:

```
#define CAMERA_TRANSFORM 1.32

camera.showsCameraControls = YES;
camera.navigationBarHidden = YES;
camera.toolbarHidden = YES;
camera.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

camera.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(camera.cameraViewTransform, CAMERA_TRANSFORM, CAMERA_TRANSFORM);
```

and for overlay you have property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *cameraOverlayView;
```

but i would recommend you to use just a addSubview to your UIImagePickerController view:

```
[camera.view addSubview:self.overlay.view];
```

Comment: @meintus using this I am able to fit the camera insida particular frame but it is not showing the camera controls... :/ can you help